# changing the color of the button in selectfield/datepicker/timepicker in Sencha

Tags: user-interface, touch, extjs

Is it possible to change the color of the button (the little triangle button) shown in the right side of selectfield/datepicker/timepicker?

Comment: You managed to get a timepicker working in ST? Which one, and does it work with ST2?

Answer (score -1):

those little triangles are constructed using images as background so you need to change those images to change color of those triangles

for datepicker image is "resources/themes/images/default/form/date-trigger.gif" in css class .x-form-date-trigger

for timepicker/selectfield image is "resources/themes/images/default/form/trigger.gif" in css class .x-form-trigger